# Positioning a div below another div

Tags: css, html

I am having difficulty positioning a div. It's supposed to below the following div but keeps appearing above it.

```
.main{
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:auto;
margin:auto;
display:block;
}
```

There are many classes in question, so I am posting my production folder instead. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eD9RG/

The div that should be below the thumbnails is

```
<div class="grid_12" id="contact">
```

I hope my question is clear enough this time.

Thank you!

Comment: Please update the question with a minimal example, online demo or the relevant code. No one will download the zip file, at least not me.

Comment: Uploaded fiddle instead. Thank you.

Comment: Try setting display property to 'inline-block' for the div with `id="contact"`.

Comment: Oh my god Vijay, I cannot believe that was all! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give:

```
display:inline-block;
```

for the div contact.